# sms content was changed by sender. how this is possible

Tags: android, sms

I want to know how is it possible that a sender is able to change the contents of an sms sent several days ago.

per instance asking a confirmation code by sms. somehow after a few days the message having the  code disappear and is replaced by other type of message saying that for security reason the message has been deleted. But it has not been deleted but the text of the message changed. I feel a breach of privacy that someone is actually getting into my phone altering contents of the messages whatever their intentions to protect my privacy are.

how is this achieved? 
see screenshoot. the sms in green was other text and the contents of the message was changed and the timestamps also altered..
[sms screenshoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3OLp9.png)

Comment: Is it an actual sms or some other messaging service?

Comment: it is an sms not other messaging service..

Comment: Attach screenshot and more details

Comment: That's a replace SMS. It's defined in the specification, and allows exactly what you're seeing there - a previously received message being replaced with a new one.

Comment: Replace SMS happens only at the SMSC. When a message is delivered to the phone, there is not such thing as replace (always new SMS)

Comment: @Marvin I'm not sure if I'm following what you're saying, but you can look at Android's source code to see that it does indeed support [replace SMS](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/opt/telephony/+/master/src/java/android/telephony/SmsMessage.java#618) on the device, and the platform SMS app [updates the old message](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Mms/+/master/src/com/android/mms/transaction/SmsReceiverService.java#486) if it is. All SMS apps should do that, though some might fail to do so.

Comment: @Mike,this flag is set only within SMSC as it can change PID (despite this flag, for the SMSC is the new message-not replaced in a db) Probably operator gave full access to the 3rd party which is sending sms (which is very rare) transparently.